# Алгоритм сортировки для выбора графических элементов мышью

Tags: java, libgdx

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать подсвечивание элемента при наведении указателя мыши.

Элементы могут быть разного размера и накладываться друг на друга, но подсвечиваться должен только один. Порядок отрисовки не должен влиять на поцесс, т.е. если элемент полностью находится под другим, он должен реагировать.

Пример: [image]

Ниже приведена моя грубая попытка.

```
for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size; i++) {
    Attachment attachment = attachments.get(i);
    attachment.update();
    if (attachment.isVisible()) {
        if (Main.ctRect.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY())) {

            if (attachment.bounds.contains(tmp.x, tmp.y)) {
                ovA++;
                if (!overedAttachments.contains(attachment, false)) {
                    overedAttachment = attachment;
                    overedAttachment.over = true;
                    overedAttachments.add(overedAttachment);
                } else {
                    if (overedAttachment != null) {
                        if (!attachment.equals(overedAttachment)) {
                            attachment.over = false;
                            overedAttachments.removeValue(attachment, false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (!attachment.equals(overedAttachment)) {
                    overedAttachments.removeValue(attachment, false);
                    attachment.over = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Кому понадобится решение - сортировка коллекции по наименьшей площади.

Comment: Вопрос 1: класс Attachments - ваш собственный класс? Вопрос 2: Должен ли быть приоритет или порядок? Если на вашем рисунке нажать на зелёный квадрат, то какой должен из них подсвечиваться? Зелёный? А почему? Потому что он меньше других, потому что он нарисован на всех остальных, или потому что у него выше приоритет? Логично, что должен быть какой-то индекс приоритета, назовём его "порядок". Тогда алгоритм будет таким: находим все квадраты, которые содержат координаты курсора или нажатия, затем выбираем из этих квадратов один с наивысшим порядком.